# Simple form as date not getting input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm making a contact form for my site using simple_form and mail_form.

Here's my code on views:

```
f.input :start_date, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year, order: [:month, :year], label: false
```

However, not getting any input from :start_date, when I made :start_date a required field, I keep getting "can't be blank" no matter what I put.

It only works when I remove as: :date, and start_date is included in the email sent by mail_form.

Comment: MAke sure your imputing the correct date format. Rails tends to take formats like **'yy-mm-dd'**

Comment: Rails date format is actually **'yyyy-mm-dd'**.

Comment: simple_form documentation has the following example: f.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                              end_year: Date.today.year - 12, discard_day: true,  order: [:month, :year] I think the problem might be it was migrated as datetime: t.datetime :start_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails date format is actually **'yyyy-mm-dd'**.

That being said, @Acacia is probably correct.

If you are usually some sort of datepicker, then in your javascript, you might want to specify the date-format like

```
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

so, if you are using jQuery datepicker then it would be:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```